# How to determine the address of an element in a square matrix given the base address?

Tags: data-structures, matrices, memory-access

I was asked this question in examination. A square matrix $M$ of size $10 \times 10$ is stored in memory with each element requiring 4 bytes of storage. If the base address at $M[0][0]$ is $1840$, determine the address at $M[4][8]$ when the matrix $M$ is stored row majorwise.
I seriously don't understand this question at all. What kind of problem is this? How to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: This is elementary school mathematics. Just do the numbers. And, to say the usual: what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? (Did you have a look at the course material?) I'm closing this for now since it's unclear what your real problem is and the answer is readily found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation).

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework question? What is the point you exactly don't get? M[0][0] is a memory location stored at some address like 0x5468792. M[4][8] is another one like 0x5478954 (numbers are not correct). The question asks you to compute the address in a multi-dimensional array, given the first pointer.